# Transfer Specific Columns from .txt to Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to transfer the data in this .txt file into a spreadsheet.

[image]

After I run the VBA I have, all the data will get transferred, so, Column A through Column E will get filled.

[image]

But I only need the data in the first 3 columns (A-C). I do not want to transfer any data after the Column C. I cannot use Range.Clear method because in my real project, Columns after the Column C contain data that cannot be erased/rewrite.

```
Sub Fill()

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Desktop\Input.txt", Destination:=Range("$A:$C") _
        )
        .Name = "Input"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

This is my code, is there a way to only transfer part (first nth columns) of the data from my text file without creating an extra helper/reference sheet? 
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to process the text file before and return in the sheet as many columns you need:

```
Sub CopyLessColumns()
 Dim strSpec As String, i As Long, colToRet As Long
 Dim arrSp As Variant, arrRez() As String, arrInt As Variant, j As Long
 Dim fso As Object, txtStr As Object, strText As String

  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  strSpec = "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Desktop\Input.txt"
  If Dir(strSpec) <> "" Then 'check if file exists
    Set txtStr = fso.OpenTextFile(strSpec)
        strText = txtStr.ReadAll
    txtStr.Close
  End If

  arrSp = Split(strText, vbCrLf)
  colToRet = 5 'Number of columns you need
  ReDim arrRez(UBound(arrSp), colToRet - 1)
  For i = 0 To UBound(arrSp)
    arrInt = Split(arrSp(i), vbTab)
    If UBound(arrInt) > colToRet - 1 Then
        For j = 0 To colToRet - 1
            arrRez(i, j) = arrInt(j)
        Next j
    End If
  Next i
  ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(UBound(arrRez, 1) + 1, UBound(arrRez, 2) + 1)).Value = arrRez
End Sub
```

I will also like to emphasize that @Ron Rosenfeld idea is brilliant, anyhow. You can just refreshing the query if/when you need it...

In order to easily use it, next piece of code gives you the possibility to build the necessary array prior to `QueryTables.Add`, in this way:

```
  Dim arrV() As Variant, i As Long, rng As Range
  Const nrCol As Long = 20 'Number of columns to be returned
  Set rng = Range("$A:$AF")

  ReDim arrV(1 To rng.Columns.count)
  For i = 1 To rng.Columns.count
     If i > nrCol Then
        arrV(i) = 9
     Else
        arrV(i) = 1
     End If
  Next i
```

And then replace the line

```
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1,...)
```

with

```
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = arrV
```

Comment: This is actually great! In my real Excel sheet, I had 168 columns and I didn't need the last 8 columns, so I was going to write the number "1" 160 times, but now I only have to change "colToRet = 5" to "colToRet = 160". Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! I offered myself to help you in your previous thread on this issue . I asked about a text sample, but you said that your code suddenly started to work as expected... :)

Comment: Yeah...2 hours after I deleted that post, I realized my code suddenly started to "work" because I forgot to erase the Range.Clear statement in the end...Anyway, thank you :) !

Answer (score 3):

Just change:

```
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

to

```
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 9, 9, 9)
```

Note that:  `xlSkipColumn` = `9`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Desktop\Input.txt", Destination:=Range("$A:$C") _
        )
        .Name = "Input"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    Activeworksheet.Range("D:F").EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment :) but as I stated in the question, I cannot use Range.Clear or Rang.Delete functions because in my real project, Column D to F will contain formulas that cannot be overwrote

Comment: I need to only update Column A - C, without effecting any other columns

Comment: Power Query - remove columns? (untested).

Comment: @BigBen nah, I think that falls under the same concept. I cannot do anything to any other columns after the Column C (not clear, remove, nor delete). I know I can solve the problem simply by creating another sheet, clean the data in another sheet, then do the transfer, but I want to avoid creating another sheet